# React Native Navigation Error building Android,:app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-navigation

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to install react-native-navigation(wix) package, I'm following the steps on android(https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-android) but in android studio the build fails with the message. Gradle 4.1( I don't know if this is related)

```
Could not resolve project :react-native-navigation.
Required by:
project :app

Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-navigation: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-navigation.
Open File
Show Details

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-navigation.
Open File
Show Details

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-navigation.
Open File
Show Details

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-navigation.
Open File
Show Details

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-navigation.
```

I leave the details below(my user is called home, is not a typo):

Issue Description
local.properties file

```
sdk.dir=/home/home/Android/Sdk
```

settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
include ':react-native-navigation'
project(':react-native-navigation').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-navigation/android/app/')
App gradle file

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.home.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
   //tried implementation as well here instead of compile but didn't work either 
   compile project(':react-native-navigation')

}
```

#### Environment

- React Native Navigation version: "1.1.370"
- React Native version: "0.52.0"
- Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?): Android
- Device info (Simulator/Device? OS version? Debug/Release?): Android Studio

Which version of gradle and android api should I use with react native? Is there any way to solve this? I see that my app gradle file is nothing alike the instructions, that compile project statement is not valid in my version of gradle. Any idea? Maybe the local.settings is wrong and is not finding the files?...Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
We also get the same problem on my android app, Here is the solution.
 Follow the steps to overcome this error.

     Step 1:

    Requirements
    node >= 8
    react-native >= 0.51

    Step 2:
    npm install --save react-native-navigation

    Step 3:
    Add the following in android/settings.gradle:

    include ':react-native-navigation'

    project(':react-native-navigation').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-navigation/lib/android/app/')

    Step 4: 
    Make sure you're using the new gradle plugin, edit android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

    distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    distributionPath=wrapper/dists
    zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
    +distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
    -distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

    Step 5:
    Update android/build.gradle:

    buildscript {
        repositories {
    +        google()
    +        mavenLocal()
    +        mavenCentral()
    +        jcenter()
    -        maven {
    -            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
    -            name 'Google'
    -        }
        }
        dependencies {
    +        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    -        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
    +        google()
    +        mavenCentral()
            mavenLocal()
            jcenter()
            maven {
                // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
                url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
            }
    -        maven {
    -            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
    -            name 'Google'
    -        }
    +        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
    }

    ext {
    -    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.3"
    +    buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
    -    minSdkVersion = 16
    +    minSdkVersion = 19
        compileSdkVersion = 26
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
    }

    Step 6:
    Update project dependencies in android/app/build.gradle.
    android {
        compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
        buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.yourproject"
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            }
        }
    +    compileOptions {
    +        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    +        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    +    }
        ...
    }

    dependencies {
    -    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    -    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    -    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    +    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    +    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    +    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    +    implementation project(':react-native-navigation')
    }

    Step 7: 
    Update MainActivity.java
    MainActivity.java should extend com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationActivity instead of ReactActivity.
    This file is located in android/app/src/main/java/com/<yourproject>/MainActivity.java.
    -import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
    +import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationActivity;

    -public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity { 
    +public class MainActivity extends NavigationActivity {
    -    @Override
    -    protected String getMainComponentName() {
    -        return "yourproject";
    -    }
    }

    Step 7:
    Update MainApplication.java
    This file is located in android/app/src/main/java/com/<yourproject>/MainApplication.java.
    ...
    import android.app.Application;

    import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
    import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
    import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
    import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
    import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

    +import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication;
    +import com.reactnativenavigation.react.NavigationReactNativeHost;
    +import com.reactnativenavigation.react.ReactGateway;

    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    -public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
    +public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {
    +    
    +    @Override
    +    protected ReactGateway createReactGateway() {
    +        ReactNativeHost host = new NavigationReactNativeHost(this, isDebug(), createAdditionalReactPackages()) {
    +            @Override
    +            protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
    +                return "index";
    +            }
    +        };
    +        return new ReactGateway(this, isDebug(), host);
    +    }
    +
    +    @Override
    +    public boolean isDebug() {
    +        return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    +    }
    +
    +    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    +        // Add additional packages you require here
    +        // No need to add RnnPackage and MainReactPackage
    +        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
    +            // eg. new VectorIconsPackage()
    +        );
    +    }
    +  
    +    @Override
    +    public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
    +        return getPackages();
    +    }
    - ...
    +}

    Step 8: 
    RNN and React Native version

    react-native-navigation supports multiple React Native versions. Target the React Native version required by your project by specifying the RNN build flavor in android/app/build.gradle.

    android {
        ...
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.yourproject"
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    +        missingDimensionStrategy "RNN.reactNativeVersion", "reactNative57" // See note below!
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

For the more details, you can follow this link 
[enter link description here](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing?id=android)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the last gradle version wasn't compatible with the package as I suspected. I had to use gradle 3 in the end and everything worked

Comment: hi, im facing the same issue. can you be more specific how you fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Environment

```
React Native Navigation version: "2.0.2502"
React Native version: "0.56.0"
Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?): Android
Device info (Simulator/Device? OS version? Debug/Release?): Android Studio
```

I followed the [official documentation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/v2/#/), then had the same issue. In my situation I moved the 'RNN' folder within my react-native project's `node_modules`, then Gradle worked.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Android SDK 27 installed? Open your Android SDK Manager in Android Studio and make sure you install that version there. Also try creating an emulator that is based on that version.